# How to get the name of Model in ValidateModelAttribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this filter that executes on all actions:-

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

*Question One: Here can I check the name of the Model? So for example, if it is a Model by Name "OpportunityManagerModel" I want to do something different. I want to return a custom error object.*

*Question Two: Can I get access to the Model itself in the method. As I want to do some Custom Validation such as examine a collection and test for a condition.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to model by using `actionContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` or by using `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments` which is dictionary and you need to write something like this to get model.

```
foreach(var arg in actionContext.ActionArguments.Values.Where(x => x is T))
{
     T model = arg as T;
}
```

And you can get name of the model like this:

```
var model = new OpportunityManagerModel();
var modelName = model.GetType().Name;
```